# Android: Otto event bus implementation

Tags: android, design-patterns, otto

I'm developing Android app which should use pagination on `RecyclerView`. I use `Executor` within `Service` to make webrequests to API and then persist fetched data in DB. To notify about changes in DB and then apply new data in my adapter I suggest to use Otto event bus. Publisher/subscriber pattern is quite new for me, so I tried to find good tutorial or explanation how this should work but after two days of search I have only foggy idea about what should I implement and how actually Event bus works. Could someone give a good hint where should I start or link on tutorial or code sample? i know that this is a really newbie question but I don't see alternative for this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best guides that I found are: from [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-EventBusOtto/article.html) and from [Codepath](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Communicating-with-an-Event-Bus). I hope it will help somebody. And good note based on my experience - Otto EventBus works **synchronously** , keep it in mind.

Answer (score -1):

import this library into your app level gradel:

```
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

create a class for Event handling:

```
public class DataSyncEvent {
    private final String syncStatusMessage;
    private final String countryName;
    private final int postion;

    public DataSyncEvent(String syncStatusMessage, int postion, String countryName) {
        this.syncStatusMessage = syncStatusMessage;
        this.postion = postion;
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public String getSyncStatusMessage() {
        return syncStatusMessage;
    }

    public String countryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public int getPostion() {
        return postion;
    }
}
```

now pass values from your class/fragment or service:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new DataSyncEvent(leftOrRight, position, countryName));
```

don't forget to register and unregister bus where you are using @Subscribe

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
```

with @Subscribe you can get that values:

```
 @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(DataSyncEvent syncStatusMessage) {


        if (syncStatusMessage.getSyncStatusMessage().contains("left")) {

            leftPosition = syncStatusMessage.getPostion();
            img_flag_left.setImageResource(countriesFlag[leftPosition]);
            leftCountryName.setText(syncStatusMessage.countryName());

        } else {
            rightPosition = syncStatusMessage.getPostion();
            img_flag_right.setImageResource(countriesFlag[rightPosition]);
            rightCountryName.setText(syncStatusMessage.countryName());
        }


    }
```